# VCHI initialization failed screen error when executing sh script from php

Tags: php, bash, raspbian

I want to trigger the screen power on a raspberry pi from an simple `php` site.

I'm using `apache 2` and `php7` on `raspbian` and the files are stored on `/var/www/html/controller` and all have chmod 777 set.

this is how my php site looks:

```
<?php
if ($_GET['on']) {
    shell_exec("/var/www/html/controller/on.sh");
}
?>
<a href="?on=true">turn on</a>
```

and my `on.sh` file like this:

```
#!/bin/bash
vcgencmd display_power 1
```

when I click the link I get the following error:

> VCHI initialization failed screen

Any suggestions how to fix this?

Answer (score 1):

I figured out that the `.sh` files need more permissions. To be more precise the user `www-data` as described here https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/127529

To do so:

1. Run the command `sudo visudo`
2. add `www-data ALL=NOPASSWD: /var/www/html/controller/` on the very end
3. modify `shell_exec("/var/www/html/controller/on.sh");` to `shell_exec("sudo /var/www/html/controller/on.sh");`